# Trigger long process in Django view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a view (start_job_view) in Django that should trigger a very long process.
I'd like the view to return immediately and add a message to the user ("your job has started" using the message framework) and I'd like that when the long process terminates it sends a new message to the user ("your job has finished").

How can I do this?

Note: I am not keen to add Celery to my project for this only task...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `async` view. You can have more details over [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/)

Another can be creating a celery task and calling it in your view.

Comment: I tried the async view but was unable to make it work. Do you have a working example with async?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-memory queue which runs on separate thread. Take a look at segment library code, which merge/process events in bg thread [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-python/blob/master/analytics/consumer.py).

Note that in case your server get terminated due to any reason you have mechanism to id job failed and retry.

Comment: It seems interesting but the code lacks explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have multiple Django server instances running that connect to a dedicated DB server. I'd just use a database table as a "queue" to store the tasks that need to run.

Then use systemd to run a Django command as worker tasks on one or more server instances. When a worker is idle, it can query the table for the next task.

Have a "status" column to mark a task as done. Then your Django frontend can check for available "done" tasks, add the message to the returned page, and remove the task from the table.

Comment: I agree that it may be the best solution for background task management but it's too much in this case.

Comment: Storing the task state in the database will ensure that on failure (task throws exception, server reboot, etc) all tasks that have not finished will be run. And no extra install (Celery) is needed, just a simple Django model to remember state.

Comment: I agree that's a clean and workable solution. I would imagine something (maybe less safe) but using multi-threading, async, subprocess, etc...

Comment: The view thread would need to wait for the subprocess to finish and keep the connection to the user open, so it can get the "done" state from the process and forward it to the user. Much simpler to separate the two parts and keep state in the DB. Also, if a user hits `F5` a hundred times, it would spawn 100 subprocesses. De-duplication is much easer with shared state (e.g. in a DB table, skip new inserts as long as a user still has a queued or running task).

Answer (score 0):

in `views.py`

```
def your_view(self, request):
   # your code          
   t = BackgroundTasksUtils(user) # Not required to pass parameter (it's up to you)
   t.start()
   return something
```

in `bg_task.py`

```
import threading

class BackgroundTasksUtils(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, user):
       super(BackgroundTasksUtils, self).__init__()
       self.user = user
   def run(self):
       # your code that taking too much time (in my case sending mail to user) 
   def __str__(self):
       return something
```

if you are not giving any parameter in `views.py` then don't forgot to remove `__init__` in `bg_task.py`

For a better and deeper understanding, visit [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Comment: Very interesting approach... will try this and let you know